# VersionSpec equivalent of /version:W

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

What is the [VersionSpec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versionspec.aspx) equivalent of "/version:W" when used with TF.EXE?

For example, Buck Hodges demonstrated the following usages (from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2009/01/26/how-to-determine-the-latest-changeset-in-your-workspace.aspx)

```
tf history . /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /version:W
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is an instance of [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.WorkspaceVersionSpec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspaceversionspec.aspx).

You can't pass empty values to the constructors, so I assume TF.EXE does that automatically